# Boto3 ECS Fargate: how to wait until task arn is available

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I am increasing a task count in a cluster with with: 'update_service()'

I am then immediatly calling: 'list_tasks(cluster=cluster_name)'
to try and get the new task arn, but the task arn is empty as there isnt one yet.

Is there any way I can wait until an arn becomes available for the task?

Sample code:

```
# increase task count to 1
response = ecs.update_service(
    cluster=cluster_name,
    service=service_name,
    desiredCount=1
)
print(response)

print("Listing tasks:")
response = ecs.list_tasks(
    cluster=cluster_name
)
print(response) # response shows blank arn

# code here that use's task arn
```

Comment: I'm not sure about this, maybe your case is special. If you need to auto-scale the number of tasks, you can use autoscaling feature.

Comment: Since you're triggering autoscaling of a service, instead of just running a task directly, I would try the Boto3 ServicesStable Waiter: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.41/reference/services/ecs.html#ECS.Waiter.ServicesStable

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, you wait for `taskSetArn` to continue the script. The below code can guide you. I'm saying "guide" because I didn't have a chance to deploy the AWS resources to check if the code works correctly. But you can tweak and correct it if necessary.

You need to periodically check the status of the existing task sets with `describe_task_sets` method. And once you get a non-null task ARN, you can go with it.

```
import boto3
import time

ecs = boto3.client('ecs')

while True:

    response = ecs.describe_task_sets(
        cluster=cluster_name, 
        service=service_name,
    )
    # For this example, the first task is going to be considered.
    task_arn = response["taskSets"][0]["taskSetArn"]

    if not task_arn:
        print("Task ARN is not available yet!")
        time.sleep(10)
        continue
    else:
        print("Task ARN is: ", task_arn)
        break
```